# JMeter JDBC Response message: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:

Tags: java, jmeter

When I connect the database with JDBC i get this:

```
[StatAggResultCollector] Test Started, host: *local*
[StatAggResultCollector] Test Ended, host: *local*
```

in response message I get:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:..
```

Any solution?
Is this from jdbc driver or from configuration?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like JMeter cannot find the Oracle driver.

Have you put the ojdbc14.jar or classes12.zip (which contains Oracle drivers) file in the JMETER/lib directory

Answer (score 3):

For Oracle database 9 and 10 use ojdbc14.jar for Oracle database 11 use ojdbc5.jar if you use java 1.5 or ojdbc6.jar if you use java 1.6. Check java version in jmeter.bat file.